# Show Last Modified Date only on Recently Modified WordPress Posts

Tags: wordpress, date, seo, comments

As a good SEO practice we are regularly refreshing our blog posts content and update the modified date. However we noticed that Google shows the date of comments in SERP. It considers date of comments to be more suitable than dates in meta that are:

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2023-11-08T01:24:26+00:00" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2023-11-09T08:06:16+00:00" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
```

Thus I would like to:

- Show the date on top of the blog post but only for recently modified posts (say those changed during the last 6 or 12 months)
- Avoid showing dates and times of all comments (I've tried many tutorials, none of them works on the recent version of Wordpress)

I guess it should be done by adding functions to Functions.php unless a plugin exists (I searched for it with no luck).

Thanks

Comment: why -1, isn't it valid wordpress question?

Answer (score 0):

**Display Date on Top of Recently Modified Posts:**

Modify Your Theme's Single Post Template:

Edit your theme's single post template (usually single.php or content-single.php) and add the following code where you want the modified date to appear:

```
<?php
$modified_date = get_the_modified_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$six_months_ago = strtotime('-6 months');
if (strtotime($modified_date) > $six_months_ago) {
    echo '<p class="modified-date">Last Updated: ' . $modified_date . '</p>';
}
?>
```

This code checks if the post was modified within the last 6 months and only displays the modified date if it meets this criterion. Adjust the value of $six_months_ago as needed.

Style the Displayed Date:
Add some CSS to your theme's stylesheet to style the displayed date:

```
.modified-date {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888;
}
```

Avoid Showing Dates and Times of All Comments:
Unfortunately, WordPress doesn't provide a built-in option to disable displaying comment dates globally. However, you can consider using custom CSS to hide comment dates. Add the following CSS to your theme's stylesheet:

```
.comment-time {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This CSS snippet targets the class associated with comment dates and hides them. Please note that this method assumes your theme uses the class .comment-time for comment dates. If your theme uses a different class, inspect the HTML source to identify the correct class and adjust the CSS accordingly.

By implementing these changes, you can control the display of modified dates on top of your blog posts based on your specified timeframe and hide the dates and times of all comments.